# How to elegantly handle NoSuchElementElement exception in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have around 20 elements to find by xpath. I'm using this.

```py
e1 = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "myclass")]').text
```

When element is not found, it throws `NoSuchElementException`.
One solution would be to use: `find_elements_by_xpath` instead.

```py
e1 = element.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "myclass")]')
# Then check for length
if len(e1) > 0:
   text1 = e1[0].text
```

That's 3 lines of codes for one single element.
If I use `try`, `except` as well, there will be 60 lines of code
more for such a trivial task.

How to handle this elegantly? Also, is there any way to find `text` directly from xpath instead of doing `element.text` like:

```py
# This should return text inside of that element
text = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "myclass")]/text()')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and best practice way, [according to the Selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)), to do this is to use `.find_elements()` as you suggested just wrap it in a function to make it more reusable, keep your code DRY, and make your code easier to read.

Rather than restricting locators to just XPath, instead use a By in your method.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def get_text(element, locator):
    elements = element.find_elements(locator)
    if len(elements) > 0:
        return elements[0].text
    return ""
```

NOTE: Return "" (empty string) here instead of `None`. If you return `None` when it's not found, you will have to check for `None` when doing something with the return or you'll get an exception.

Then you call it like

```
e1 = get_text(element, (By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class, "myclass")]'))
```

or better yet, use a CSS selector because it's faster, better supported, and in this scenario less likely to give you unintended elements.

```
e1 = get_text(element, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.myclass"))
```

Also, you can't use `/text()` in an XPath in a browser because browsers only support XPath 1.0 and `/text()` is in a later version.

Comment: You say `find_elements()` is "The simplest and best practice way (according to the Selenium docs)" -- could you please link me to such docs for my own learning?

Comment: @C.Peck I was looking for it as you asked the question... :). I updated my answer with the link. The important bit is `findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.`

Comment: Nice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are writing some code that you expect may cause an exception, so try/except is the right way to handle it. It shouldn't need **60** lines of code, just write and call a function like this, is what I would do:

```
def text_if_element_found_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
        return text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return ""
```

Then your code in your test is simply

```
text1 = text_if_element_found_by_xpath(xpath1)
text2 = text_if_element_found_by_xpath(xpath2)
...
```

Regarding this:

Also, is there any way to find `text` directly from xpath instead of doing `element.text` like:

```
# This should return text inside of that element
text = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "myclass")]/text()')
```

1. I think `element.text` is the best way to do this. `find_element_by_xpath()` will **always** return an element (or cause an exception), not text/a string, so there is no xpath that will just grab the text for you.
2. Even if it could work, would your example code be preferable to this?

```
text = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "myclass")]').text
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `null` in python.

Comment: The equivalent of null is `None`.

Comment: @JeffC Oops. I'm bad at python, thanks for pointing that out.